# data.matrix returning only values after decimal and turning negative values into positive in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (mydf) that looks like this

```
       I       II
A      1.2    -2.1
B     -2.3     4.2
C      3.8    -6.4
D      4.5     8.7
```

For some reason these values are not being considered numeric. So I tried using

```
mydm <- data.matrix(mydf)
```

to solve it.
However, it returns

```
      I    II
A     2    1
B     3    2
C     8    4
D     5    7
```

data.matrix seems to have no other arguments related to this, so I feel pretty much stuck. Any workaround?

Comment: You should use `type.convert(df)` instead

Answer (score -1):

We can use

```
mydm[] <-  (abs(mydm)* 10)%% 10
```

#### data

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, as.numeric)
mydf <- data.matrix(mydf)
mydm <- structure(c(1.2, -2.3, 3.8, 4.5, -2.1, 4.2, -6.4, 8.7), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c("I", "II")))
```

Answer (score -1):

Another base R option

```
mydm[] <- lapply(mydm, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("^.*\\.", "", x)))
```

**Data**

```
> dput(mydm)
structure(list(I = c(1.2, -2.3, 3.8, 4.5), II = c(-2.1, 4.2,
-6.4, 8.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C",
"D"))
```